# Android data-binding not working when using inflate() of binding class

Tags: java, android, android-databinding

I'm new to data binding. I have a layout file as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable name="userProfile" type="com.demo.entity.UserProfile"/>
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="16dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/username_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@{userProfile.username}" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

I'm trying to use data binding in android as per the documentation's second method given [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#binding_data). I'm not using the first method because I'm inflating the concerned layout into a frame layout which is part of a DrawerLayout in an abstract class so that same navigation drawer can be used across activities [I intend to avoid the complications nested fragments lead to].

Hence my code looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    inflateActivityViewInFrame(R.layout.activity_profile, R.string.action_profile);
    initialiseData();
}

private void initialiseData() {
    ActivityProfileBinding binding = ActivityProfileBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    UserProfile userProfile = new UserProfile("Croaking Tiger Riding Dragon", 8, 16, 32);
    binding.setUserProfile(userProfile);
}
```

The inflateActivityViewInFrame() method in the parent class does only this:

```
protected void inflateActivityViewInFrame(int layoutId, int titleStringId) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(layoutId, mFrameLayout, false);
    mFrameLayout.addView(view);

    setupActionBarAndDrawerToggle(titleStringId);
}
```

The code compiles fine and there are no log messages either in runtime.
The entity class is (followed by public getters of all the properties)

```
public class UserProfile {
    private final String username;
    private final int numContributions;
    private final int numBookmarks;
    private final int numLikes;

    public UserProfile(String username, int numContributions, int numLikes, int numBookmarks) {
        this.username = username;
        this.numContributions = numContributions;
        this.numBookmarks = numBookmarks;
        this.numLikes = numLikes;
    }
```

Any thoughts why this isn't working?

Comment: because your field is private

Comment: @Beloo All the fields have public getters... sorry didn't attach that code to keep it short but it's like I've mentioned in the question :)

Comment: Just to add, the layout is fine as well, in that it is displaying when a constant string is used instead of bound data in android:text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're inflating the layout in `inflateActivityViewInFrame` and then inflating it again (unattached) in `initialiseData`. You can choose to do one or the other. Either this:

```
protected <T extends ViewDataBinding> T inflateActivityViewInFrame(
        int layoutId, int titleStringId) {
  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
      getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  T binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, layoutId, mFrameLayout, true);
  setupActionBarAndDrawerToggle(titleStringId);
}
```

and then use the return ViewDataBinding to set the data:

```
ActivityProfileBinding binding = 
    inflateActivityViewInFrame(R.layout.activity_profile, R.string.action_profile); 
UserProfile userProfile = new UserProfile("Croaking Tiger Riding Dragon", 8, 16, 32);
binding.setUserProfile(userProfile);
```

Or, you could just bind the already-inflated layout.

```
protected View inflateActivityViewInFrame(int layoutId, int titleStringId) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(layoutId, mFrameLayout, false);
    mFrameLayout.addView(view);

    setupActionBarAndDrawerToggle(titleStringId);
    return view;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflateActivityViewInFrame(
        R.layout.activity_profile, R.string.action_profile);
    initialiseData(view);
}

private void initialiseData(View view) {
    ActivityProfileBinding binding = ActivityProfileBinding.bind(view);
    UserProfile userProfile = new UserProfile("Croaking Tiger Riding Dragon", 8, 16, 32);
    binding.setUserProfile(userProfile);
}
```

I always prefer the former to the latter as it lets the binding happen as close to the inflation as possible.

Comment: Thanks a ton for that, from the developer guide I didn't realise all this API existed!